# facing wired kind of output array sort in php

Tags: php, arrays, sorting

i know this is a simple question to ask but i am facing wired kind of problem.

i am scanning some pdf using scandir(). here is the following code i use

```
<?php
$dir    = 'download/';
$files = scandir($dir);
sort($files);

        for ($i=2; $i <count($files); $i++) { 

            echo "<a href=download/$files[$i]>$files[$i]</a> ";
            echo "<br>";
        }
print_r($files);
?>
```

as per my exp it should give me output as oder

```
1.pdf
2.pdf
.
.
.
.
.
.
.
10.pdf
11.pdf
```

this way but  what i get in output is following

```
1.pdf
10.pdf
11.pdf
2.pdf
.
.
.
.
.
.

11.pdf
```

also if i print_r() to check the array it show following

```
 Array ( [0] => . [1] => .. [2] => 1.pdf [3] => 10.pdf [4] => 2.pdf [5] => principal 10.pdf [6] => principal11.pdf [7] => principal12.pdf [8] => principal13.pdf [9] => principal14.pdf [10] => principal15.pdf [11] => principal16.pdf [12] => principal4.pdf [13] => principal5.pdf [14] => principal6.pdf [15] => principal7.pdf [16] => principal8.pdf [17] => principal9.pdf ) 1
```

i would really appreciate your help.

Comment: You used `<br>` for line break, so it works as expected, isn't it? Or do you mean the sorting sequence? The sort sequence you are looking for is called "natural sorting". See [natsort()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.natsort.php)

Comment: yes i mean sorting sequence. is not it should show 1 2 3 4 7 this way insted of 1 10 11 2 3 ?

Comment: if you look at the print_r() array 10.pdf [3] => 10.pdf  in array no 3 but what should not be it should be [3] => 2.pdf .

Comment: That's why I quote the `natsort()` for you. Read the link above.

Comment: i just use natsort() but its doesnot make any difference same output as above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should replace `sort($files)` with `natsort($files)`, which implements natural sorting.

Testing Codes:

```
$array = array('1.pdf', '10.pdf', '2.pdf', '3.pdf', '6.pdf', '11.pdf');
natsort($array);
print_r($array);
```

which outputs:

```
Array
(
    [0] => 1.pdf
    [2] => 2.pdf
    [3] => 3.pdf
    [4] => 6.pdf
    [1] => 10.pdf
    [5] => 11.pdf
)
```

to loop through the `$array`, use `foreach` instead of `for` loop, which relies on array key. For example:

```
foreach($array as $file) {
  if($file == '.' || $file == '..') {
    continue;
  }
  echo $file . '<br />';
}
```

Reference: [natsort()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.natsort.php)

Side note: Your HTML code is invalid. You should surround the `href` value with quotes.

Comment: Dear @raptor, i am really appreciate your help i am not an expart of php . but when i use natsort() it show following output http://silenceithouse.com/test/    

here is the simple line of code i use 
[code]
<?php
$dir    = 'download/';
$files = scandir($dir);
natsort($files);

  for ($i=2; $i <count($files); $i++) { 
   
   echo "<a href=download/$files[$i]>$files[$i]</a> ";
   echo "<br>";
  }
print_r($files);
?>[code]

Comment: `$i` starts from 2 ? The problem in your codes lie in for loop, as you use the array key to show the contents. As you can see from my example, the keys are re-arranged, thus it cannot be used to loop. Use `foreach` loop instead.

Comment: thanks man.. thats works great .yes i start from 2 because i just get rid of 1st 2 element which is . .. can you tell me what could i used to get rid those  . and  .. in forech() ?

Comment: If I were you, I will loop all elements and skip unwanted elements with `continue`.